# App Store link not shown in app-invites email

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I'm trying to implement App Invites in our application, but I can't get the iOS clients to link to the App Store. They always show the Play store link.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app),  we need to call *setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication* if we have more than one iOS client id in our project in developers console. The thing is, if I try to add our iOS app client id, the email is never sent

```
.setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication(PROJECT_PLATFORM_IOS,
                    "104XXXXXXXXXX-i089XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com")
```

If I omit this call, the email is sent but it points to Play store.

Anyway, inspecting google-services.json only shows one iOS client id

```
{
    "project_info": {
        ...
    },
    "client": [
        {
            "client_info": {
                "package_name": "com.mycompany"
            },
            "oauth_client": [
                ...
            ],
            "api_key": [

            ],
            "services": {
                "appinvite_service": {
                    "status": 2,
                    "other_platform_oauth_client": [
                        {
                            "client_id": "XXXXXX-YYYYY.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                            "client_type": 2,
                            "ios_info": {
                                "bundle_id": "com.mycompany.app",
                                "app_store_id": "123456789"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "client_id": "XXXXXX-JJJJJJJJ.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                            "client_type": 3
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        [
            another client info for the debug package name
        ],
        "client_info": [

        ],
        "ARTIFACT_VERSION": "1"
    }
```

I don't know what else I can try, any idea is welcome

I'm using AS 2.0 preview 9, and *2.0.0-alpha9* versions for *android* and *google-services*' gradle plugin. Also, as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin?hl=en), I've placed the apply plugin at the bottom of *app/build.gradle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had 2 credentials that shared the same *Bundle ID*.

Furthermore, the most recently added (and the only one listed in *google-services.json*) was not being used. Once I deleted it, the real credential was added to the json file and the call to *setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication* worked just fine.

Comment: Can you share your google-service.json structure, where iOS app is working?

Comment: the google-services.json is in the question, I didn't have to change the structure, only the client_id. Anyway this is 9 months old now and invites was in beta, maybe they've changed something. To start with, it looks like it's been integrated into Firebase. I've tested on my app (old project I no longer work on) and the link generated for the email seems to work fine on apps but not when opened from desktop browser.